# Error (There was no endpoint listening at) while consuming the WCF SOAP Service from Asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Good Morning,

When I am trying to access WCF SOAP Service from Asp.net in machine A, I am getting below error, whereas when I try to test the same service from the  same  machine A using SOAP UI tool, service is giving the response as expected. I got a chance to met with service team, even with their code also its not working. My error and code is shown below, I am struggling to resolve this issue from the last few days and have gone through many articles and posts as well, but with no luck.
**Error**:
There was no endpoint listening at  https://abc.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance that could accept the message. 
 This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

inner exception:
 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
 because connected host has failed to respond 212.12.180.147:443

I am sure it is not connection or IP address or firewall issue, because using SOAP UI tool, I am getting the response as expected from this same machine. Below is my code. Kindly help what I am missing here.

```
using Consume_REDF_FourTimesAuth.ServiceReference1;

try
{
      FinanceClient objFinanceClient = new FinanceClient("WSHttpBinding_IFinance");
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((se, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
                objFinanceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "abc";
                objFinanceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "13456";
                Credential objCredentials = new Credential();
                objCredentials.UserName = "xyz";
                objCredentials.Password = "123456";

      var Response = objFinanceClient.getRealEstateRegions(objCredentials);
      //var Response = objFinanceClient.getCalculaterV2(objCredentials, 123456, 22.2, 11.1, 12, 202, 24, 06, "10/06/1987", 
      //                                                2, "02/11/2019", 22.2, 2, 2, 22.2, 2, 22.2);
      lblDisplay.Text = Response.ToString();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     throw ex;
}
```

Below entries made automatically in web.config, after adding service reference.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IFinance">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IFinance"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IFinance" name="WSHttpBinding_IFinance">
        <identity>
          <dns value="webservice.redf.gov.sa" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You need to contact whoever owns https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc and ask them if the domain and path is correct. Nothing we can do. What you have looks okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

check this post [There Was No Endpoint Listening at http // That Could Accept The Message in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169169/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-http-that-could-accept-the-message-in-wcf)

The issue maybe in the endpoint in web.config

try to replace:
https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance

with:
https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance/webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance

Or:
https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried both, but getting same error with just message change. Like.  There was no endpoint listening at https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc   and for second change.. There was no endpoint listening at https://webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance/webservice.redf.gov.sa/RedfFinance.Finance.svc/RedfFinance

Answer (score 0):

Finally after so many days of struggle, it worked.the server was not allowing direct call. So we had to proxy explicitly.
Please see this thread for more info..
https://forums.asp.net/t/2162245.aspx?There+was+no+endpoint+listening+at+https+ABC+redf+gov+sa+RedfFinance+Finance+svc+RedfFinance+that+could+accept+the+message+